# Reference request on the rank computation of symbolic matrices using numerical methods with arbitrary precision

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-rank, symbolic-computation

I need to compute the rank of matrices with symbolic entries. At some complexity level this is unreliable, so I am looking for alternatives, e.g. substituting random numbers for each symbol and then computing the rank numerically, or computing the singular values. Both ideas result in the problem of determining if an entry is zero, or just close to zero which can be solved using a numerical tool with arbitrary precision functionality. I feel like there must be literature on this topic and possibly more elaborated methods, but i fail to find anything, so help is much appreciated!

Comment: Take some high prime and fill the variables with random integers modulo that prime. Compute the rank with all operations in modular arithmetic. Repeat for some more primes. In the end you are testing if certain determinants are zero, whatever way you compute them. These are polynomials in the matrix entries. Testing polynomials in this way is explored in some depth, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma

Comment: ahh, thank you very much! this looks very interesting!

Comment: You should make your question more explicit because an arbitrary matrix $A = \left( {{a_{ij}}} \right)$ is such a symbolic matrix! Concrete examples would help. Are you considering real symbolic matrices? Perhaps what you're looking for is something like the **structural rank** of a matrix, see e.g. https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprank.html

Comment: My entries are meromorphic functions. However, I am more interested in the method (and not a matlab user), but good to know anyway, so thanks!

Comment: @LutzLehmann Could you elaborate a bit on why one should take high primes, why the modulo and why to repeat this procedure several times?

Comment: You do not strictly need high primes, but each of the determinants, evaluated at rational points, has prime factors in the numerator, and some of them might be there for structural reasons. With using high primes, the likelyhood of hitting such a factor is lower, with low primes you need to try more primes and more trials per prime to get the same likelihood of computing the rank correctly.